# Default label styles for itemize environment

Tags: lists, itemize, bullets

I'm creating a CV, and when I tried to use a custom label for different list environments I had trouble matching the label to the default one created by the itemize environment. So I'm wondering what the default label style is for at least the outermost entry of itemize.

Here is a MWE (correct initialism use? Also minimal might be relative):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{\raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}}{\raggedright\hintstyle{#2}}{}{}
\name{First}{Last}
\address{City, State ZIPNUM}{}
\mobile{xxx-xxx-xxxx}
\email{email@email.com}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace{-9ex}
\section{list item}
\cvitem{sublist item}{
\begin{itemize}
\item [\color{color1}$\circ$] This is using $\backslash$circ
\item [\color{color1}\boldsymbol{$\circ$}] This is using $\backslash$boldsymbol$\backslash$circ
\item [\color{color1}\bm{$\circ$}] This is using $\backslash$bm$\backslash$circ
\item This is a regular item
\item [\large\color{color1}\boldsymbol{$\circ$}] This is using $\backslash$large$\backslash$boldsymbol$\backslash$circ
\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image example of label styles]

The default (regular) one seems to be bolder than when only using \circ. \boldsymbol seems good, until I zoom in, then it looks less circular than the default (which could be a problem with mine and others eyesight).

So can someone let me know what the default is? Or redirect me to a stackexchange discussion about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use TeX's `\show` command to inspect the definition of a macro. So we check the definition of `\item` which (after some expansions) leads us to `\labelitemi`, the label for first order items in an itemize:

```
> \labelitemi=macro:
->\strut \textcolor {color1}{\marvosymbol {123}}.
```

And indeed

```
\cvitem{sublist item}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item = \textcolor {color1}{\marvosymbol {123}}
\end{itemize}}
```

gives

[image]

**EDIT:** `moderncv` loads its default symbols from a file `moderncviconsawesome.sty`. There we find the definition

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\tiny\faCircleO}}
```

This font (which requires the `fontawesome` package) is only loaded when compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. With `latex` or `pdflatex` the symbol font switches to `marvosym`, which gives the result shown above.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't loaded when compiling with  (pdf)latex? It has been some time since  the `fontawesome` package (and fonts) can be used with (pdf)latex.

Comment: @Bernard You're right, the package documentation says the same. Looks like I haven't updated my packages for some time :)

Comment: The `marvosym` worked. I greatly appreciate your answer! I feel like `\show` is the equivalent to define, def, help, or ? in other programs, so I'm sorry if it was something every latex user should know before asking a question here. I'll definitely now be testing it out! (:

Comment: @siracusa the above comment was meant to reach you.

Comment: @ChristinaTran I don't think this command is used very often by the normal LaTeX user, it's more one of TeX's low-level debugging commands. You find more of these commands explained in [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic).

Answer (score 2):

Here is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textcolor{mycolor}{\tiny\faicon{circle-o}}] This is using 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Note** `mycolor` is defined by  *moderncv* (blue theme color) as `color1`.